# Android Kotlin Room:How do I know how many tables in my zoom-database?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have used room to create a database. and also create three tables in database.
I need to know how many tables I have in my database. In this case, it will return 3 to me. Is it possible implement? How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
            Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "Table Name: "+cursor.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```